# Segfault when run emulated device on Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: 21.10, android-studio

On fresh Ubuntu 21.10 and last Android Studio, I fail to run emulated device :

[image: AVD]

[image: Error message]

Terminal say :

```
2021-12-22 23:28:43,721 [ 157557]   WARN - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator terminated with exit code 139
```

And journcalctl :

```
déc. 22 23:32:32 ion kernel: MainLoopThread[34651]: segfault at 0 ip 000000000135b8fb sp 00007fd876fa0390 error 6 in qemu-system-x86_64[dd2000+16f2000]
déc. 22 23:32:32 ion kernel: Code: 56 53 50 49 89 f6 48 89 fb bf 01 00 00 00 e8 6c ce 08 00 48 89 df 4c 89 f6 e8 11 ff ff ff 48 c7 04 24 00 00 00 00 48 8b 04 24 <c7> 00 21 05 00 00 e8 9a 0e 16 01 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 41
```

My Android Studio version:

```
Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 4
Build #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7935034, built on November 21, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Linux 5.13.0-22-generic
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 4
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: org.jetbrains.kotlin
Current Desktop: KDE
```

Any idea about the problem ? Thanks a lot if ideas !

Comment: Do you really have 2 Gb of RAM?

Comment: Hello @N0rbert , My computer have ` 12178100 kB`  of RAM. I think 2048M ,here is a java configuration for android studio.